# Android hardware dev kits?

Tags: android, i2c, spi, android-hardware

I'm faced with the task to write a driver for Android (OS 2.3 and 2.4) to interface with a sensor chip over either SPI or I2C.

The device is intended to be used in Android smart phones eventually, based on either the Intel Medfield or the Qualcomm 8 series platforms.

I assume that I don't have to worry about actually writing the SPI or I2C driver myself, right? Do you know of any current SPI or I2C drivers for Android I could use?

I will also need find a hardware development kit which allows me to access the SPI or I2C bus. Do you have a recommendation where I could find a suitable kit, which is representative of the hardware typically found in a current Android smart phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know specifically about what you're developing, but have used a freescale hardware dev kit in the past for similar work.
They have it.

Comment: Do you have a specific reference so I could look it up?

Comment: I will have to ask the guys who were with me during that time, since I forgot the model number. hold on, I may post it here after some hours.

Comment: I guess it was this model: http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=i.MX515 in picture it is shown as a NetBook, but we had got it naked and connected our peripherals. I'll confirm soon